# Как определить возникновение ошибки после последней операции?

Tags: mysql

Можно ли каким-то образом определить, что после последней операции `INSERT`/`DELETE`/`UPDATE` возникла ошибка, чтобы сделать условный откат операции в транзакции?

К примеру, в MS SQL Server для данной задачи можно использовать системную переменную `@@ERROR`, которая принимает ненулевое значение при возникновении ошибки после проведения последней операции. Вот так выглядит ее использование:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO Customers(cust_id, cust_name)
VALUES(’1000000010’, ’Toys Emporium');
SAVE TRANSACTION StartOrder;
INSERT INTO Orders(order_num, order_date, cust_id)
VALUES(20100,’2001/12/1’,’1000000010’);
IF @@ERROR <> 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION StartOrder;
```

Можно ли реализовать что-то подобное для MySQL? 
PS: Я не использую PHP.

Comment: `Можно ли реализовать что-то подобное для MySQL?` Конечно. Для этого существует CREATE HANDLER.

Answer (score 0):

Вот к примеру, маленкий скриптик, который проверяет запрос на ошибку, и потом может выполнить действие которое вам нужно.

```
function q($page,$query){ 
    // $page 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    if (mysql_errno()) { 
      $error = "MySQL error ".mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."\n<br>When executing:<br>\n$query\n<br>"; 
      $log = mysql_query("INSERT INTO db_errors (error_page,error_text) VALUES ('$page','".escape_data($error)."')"); 
    } 
    }
```